# Не работает vertical-align

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть родительский div (зеленый на примере-рисунке) и есть два независимых div-блока с текстом и прочими элементами внутри (красный на рисунке).

В левом мало текста, а во втором — много.

Требуется, чтобы элементы слева всегда были посередине относительно элементов справа, как на рисунке этом:

[image: нужный результат]
<sub>(источник: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/E2pvkBESBnbvWr.png))</sub>

Я знаю, что для этого ворде как нужно использовать vertical-align: middle, но результат не тот, что нужен. Получается идентично как если бы я bottom написал.

Comment: Приложите код, пожалуйста, тогда людям будет проще Вам помочь :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не очень правильно понимаете как работает и главное как *не работает* `vertical-align`. Чтобы добиться нужного вам результата потребуется для дочерних `div` задать `display: table-cell;` (и убрать `float`)

Ссылка по теме: [Разбираемся с vertical-align](http://web-standards.ru/articles/vertical-align/)

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1** `display: inline-block;`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
}

.col {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}

.col+.col {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, voluptas.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, voluptas.
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2** `display: table-cell;`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  display: table;
}

.col {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, voluptas.
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, voluptas.
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 3** `display: flex;`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.col {
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, voluptas.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, voluptas.
  </div>
</div>
```